# key events in java

Tags: java

i have tried a lot ...as you all gave me the code segments as a solution...but still the same error is occured...so can anyone give me the solution...
It seems a big oversight that the Robot cannot be used to enter basic non-alphanumeric characters.

Is there a cross-platform API that converts characters to key strokes?

Comment: That's four threads you start on the same topic. You should answer (in comments) to people answering you (if you have any problem with their solutions) instead of diluting information like you do.

Answer (score 0):

`KeyStroke.getKeyStroke()`